# Riemann integral problem 4

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

How can I evaluate the following limit with Riemann integral not with telescoping series:

$$ u_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n n\cdot \arctan\left(\frac{1}{k^2+k+1}\right),$$
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }u_n=\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n n\cdot \arctan\left(\frac{1}{k^2+k+1}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty\ }\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int_0^1\:f\left(x\right)dx$$

Comment: Is the "$n$" term in the summation supposed to be a $k$? As is is currently stated the term $1/n$ cancels the $n$ terms and leaves the series in question being \begin{align} u_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{k^{2} + k + 1} \right) .\end{align} As it stands the helpfulness of Jack's solution will lead to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration by parts gives:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}\right)\,dx = \arctan\frac{1}{3}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(1+2x)}{(1+x^2)(1+(x+1)^2)}\,dx$$
and the last integral equals:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{x+1}{1+(x+1)^2}+\frac{1}{1+(x+1)^2}\right)\,dx =\frac{2\log 2-\log 5}{2}+\arctan 2-\frac{\pi}{4}$$
so, in the most compact form:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}\right)\,dx = \arctan\frac{3}{4}+\log\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}.$$
Don't you think something went wrong when converting your partial sums into Riemann sums?

Comment: okay dude, but you have $$n\cdot \arctan\left(\frac{1}{k^2+k+1}\right)$$ where is n? and the final result should not be pi/2 ?

Comment: @AndreiMihai: I was just pointing out that it is not so easy to write $$n\cdot\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1+k+k^2}\right)$$ as $f(k/n)$, but I computed the integral by assuming $f(x)=\arctan\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}$ whatsoever.

Comment: so to understand, does not matter n in this case?

Comment: @AndreiMihai: there is no $n$ in my proof, I just computed the integral by assuming $f(x)=\arctan\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}$.